# Filtering Contacts Returns Mixed Contact Information - Swift

Tags: swift, search, filter, contacts

I am a new Swift developer.  I have successfully pulled the contacts from the phone and saved them in an array of Contacts, each of which has this structure:

```
struct Contact {

var contactDetails:CNContact
var isFavorite:Bool
```

The array is called deviceContacts.

I also set up an empty array of Contacts called searchResults.

I have a search bar in the contacts table that I would like to automatically filter the contacts as you type.  I am able to do this successfully with the following code for the Search Bar:

```
extension ContactsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    searchResults = deviceContacts.filter{($0.contactDetails.familyName.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText)}
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()

    // This does not work.  It filters by the last name.  But it keeps John as the first name, etc. It does not pull the full contact.

}    
}
```

Although this function will search as you type, and filter the results in realtime as you type more characters, the results are mixed up.  They show the correct last names, but the wrong first names.  The first names start at the top of the list.  So, for example, if you search the standard contacts in the simulator for "Bell" you will get Bell, John.  Bell is the second person in the list and John is the first person in the list.

I tried using the predicate search for contacts for this, but I could not get it to search as you type in real time like this function does.

Is there a way to pull the full contact when searching?  Or a way to pull just a reference to the Contact that matches and put that Contact into the searchResults array?  Or a way to use the predicate method to search as you type?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cellForRowAt I made a mistake and did not change the reference to the searchResults for the first name, only for the last name. Here is the code for the tableView:

```
if searching {
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].contactDetails.familyName+", "+searchResults[indexPath.row].contactDetails.givenName
} else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = deviceContacts[indexPath.row].contactDetails.familyName+", "+deviceContacts[indexPath.row].contactDetails.givenName
}
```